# Is there a remote shutter wi-fi app for the canon 6D for time lapse photography?

Tags: timelapse, remote, canon-6d

I use the EOS Remote app but you can only take single shots and bursts ie. no timer controlled shots like you can do with a remote shutter for time lapses. Surely there must be an app out there that can do this?

Comment: maybe Relevant link: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29356/shooting-a-timelapse-without-any-intervalometer/30421#30421

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use the [DSLR controller](http://dslrcontroller.com/guide-wifi.php) for Android

Though, for time lapse I would suggest magic lantern.
Although it's not officially released, nor officially stable, I'm using it on mine and it's stable.

You can do timelapses from within the camera.

[6d Magic Lantern Forum](http://www.magiclantern.fm/forum/index.php?topic=3904.msg21154#msg21154) and 
[6d Magic Lantern pre-alpha downloads](https://bitbucket.org/OtherOnePercent/tragic-lantern-6d/downloads)

Comment: Magic Lantern is definitely the option to go with. And you'll get lots of other features along not just timelapse.

Comment: I have never used magic lantern and to be honest I'm a bit scared to install it. Would be nice if there is an iphone app that can do it via wi-fi.

Comment: @Bernard - See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26695/what-are-the-risks-of-using-magic-lantern

Comment: Did not know that they had moved that far along with magic lantern for the 6D. I hope they come out with a final build some day.

Comment: I'm running the "[113] Check4Regression.zip" version form the pre-alpha downloads. It works well. It kills Raw Processing (cos the raw video guys need more ram. But one can boot with Magic Lantern off and then it works. Personally, with this pre-alpha, I've had some "quirks" at times. But they were worked-around/resolved quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Bernard, I just realised your question did not specify a mobile phone app.

On the 6d though, you can wifi to your laptop and run EOS Utility and use that for a timer release. See [this quick guide to use EOS Utility](http://learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/CDLC_EOSUtility_RemoteOp_QuickGuide.pdf)

If you don't have a wifi router avail, you can make an ad-hoc network to your laptop and have the 6d connect to it. The 6d DOES take longer to connect to an ad-hoc network than a router though. At least with the laptop being win7.

Alternatively if you dont' want to make an adhoc network, you can turn your phone into a wireless hotspot and connect both the laptop and the camera to it.